# Apple Numbers : countif and stats

Tags: ms-office, numbers

I have a sheet with a few columns,

*Columns A contain dates,* *Columns T contain some text*

What function can I use to count :

1. The numbers of result in the **columns A** which match the current day

I tried COUNTIF(Table 1::A2:A72, DATE(TODAY()))

2. The number of recurrence of the same text on **columns T** (e.g how many time "Approved" is listed on T

I tried  `=COUNTIF(T1:T99,"Approved")` but this return an error

Update for question 2 COUNTIF(Sheet 1::Table 1::T1:99, "Approved") is actually working

Answer (score 2):

1. COUNTIF(Table 1::A2:A72, A3)
   and add manually the date on A3
2. COUNTIF(Sheet 1:T1:99, "Approved")